# Can I select an element that finish with "string_ID"?

Tags: jquery

On server side, I generate some div with these IDS, for example :

```
<div id="ContentPlaceBody_Example_localita_168">Hello</div>
<div id="ContentPlaceBody_Example_localita_80">my name is</div>
<div id="ContentPlaceBody_Example_localita_740">Marco</div>
```

so, on client side, Id like to select these IDS checking the last part of the ID (that is fixed, can't change, `_localita_UNIQUEID`). Such as :

```
var myID = "80";
$('# HERE THE SELECTOR I NEED _localita_'+myID).hide();
```

is there a fast way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ends with selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Try this:

```
var myID = "80";
$('div[id$="localita_'+myID + '"]').hide();
```

**Update:**
@raina77ow 's comment made me dig more and here's an alternatives to make it better.

(Refer to the excellent post on this: http://encosia.com/11-keystrokes-that-made-my-jquery-selector-run-10x-faster/)

Give a class name to the divs (e.g: "endswith") you need to query by ends with and then use this version to make it perform better:

```
var myID = "80";
$('div.endswith[id$="localita_'+myID + '"]').hide();
```

Comment: @raina77ow Absolutely not compared to the id,class selectors.

Comment: Thanks raina77ow and Chandu for this class selector suggestion. I never thought of that!

Comment: Yes, adding a class will be the perfect solution indeed. )

Comment: Btw, I wonder why you guys use double quotes inside attribute selector? It's not actually required: "...anything **other** than a simple identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks...", quoting the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: @raina77ow its just the style I opt for so that I am consistent when using a simple identifier or a different identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, try this:

```
$('div [id*=\"_Example_localita_\"+ myid]).hide();
```